# Is there some better documentation somewhere for Arduino classes and API's?

Tags: documentation

For example, it looks like Serial extends HardwareSerial, which extends Stream, which extends Print. But I don't think you can figure this out by reading the reference documentation on https://www.arduino.cc/ and it doesn't appear that you can easily navigate the class hierarchy in the Arduino IDE. They seem to go out of their way to hide the class hierarchy?

I guess I'm spoiled by modern languages that have automatically generated documentation, but it seems like there should be a more complete reference somewhere?

Comment: I use Eclipse with Sloeber plugin. It gives me super powers in Arduino world

Comment: The point of Arduino is that it's targeted at people that don't need (or care) about such level of detail in the documentation.

Comment: There's an addon to MS VisualStudio (VisualMicro.com) to provide you with a *real* IDE allowing to drill down the provided core libraries.

Answer (score 1):

What I did/do when loading a new core is generating a [doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl) visualisation help class hierachy in HTML. Although most of the core libs have no detailed doxygen documenation the [dot/graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) solves the problem without installation of other IDEs (which also have their specific problems, or need a lot of learning). 
As an added bonus I can document my source code in a clean and transparent way available in most IDEs and OS.